# Передача QSqlTableModel или QSortFilterProxyModel между потоками

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qthread

Для представления данных используется модель `QSortFilterProxyModel`, в которой фильтруются данные `QSqlTableModel`.

Но при это основное окно виснет.

Почитал документацию - говорят что модель в другой поток поместить нельзя.

Возможно есть у кого то решения этой проблемы?

На каких то легких примерах или какие-то уже найденные решения...

Comment: а нафига "передавать"? почему просто не создать модель в потоке

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev, тогда наверное нельзя будет для этой модели сделать `QTableView::setModel`, а view должен быть в главном потоке

Comment: тут видимо надо делать свою модель, чтобы она в другой поток, где база открыта слала запросы/сигналы, а пока идёт обработка в другом потоке data() может возвращать значения неизвестных ячеек, как "wait..." например

Comment: А старый добрый QEventLoop не пробовали? Уходить в loop.exec после запроса и выходить из него по приходу данных? Я не пробовал, кажется, что так можно.